# Printing out a '0' for each left subtree traversal and '1' for each right subtree traversal

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>
#define n 5

struct node
{
    int num;
    struct node *left;
    struct node *right;
}*root_ptr, *current, *previous, *newNode;

void getCodes(struct node *);

char *symbols[] = {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E"}, **p=symbols;
char codeKeeper[32]={0}, *code_ptr = codeKeeper;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    //some code

    //tree structure formation
    getCodes(root_ptr);
    return 0;
}
void getCodes(struct node *no)
{
    if(no!=NULL)
    {
        *code_ptr++ = '0';
        getCodes(no->left);
        if(no->left==NULL)
            printf("%d left child is %s having code as %s0\n", no->num, *p++, codeKeeper+1);
        if(no->right==NULL)
            printf("%d right child is %s having code as %s1\n", no->num, *p++, codeKeeper+1);
        *(--code_ptr) = '1';
        getCodes(no->right);
    }
}
```

The tree formed is

> ```
>             2
>     1               3
>                            4
> ```

What i want to do is print a '0' for each left branch traversal and '1' for each right branch traversal, so i used in-order traversal. Also when i traverse in inorder fashion, it must check for each node whether it doesnt have left subtree or right subtree or both, and accordingly print out symbols(with a 0 and 1 appened) from left to right filling up NULL pointers as and when encountered.

My `getCodes()` function is able to print out only 2 chars from right .. the above depth of tree and its code is eaten up or not populated.

Edit:
Symbol "A" must be left child of 1, Symbol "B" must be right child of 1 .. like this the tree leaves must be identified dynamically while traversing

so final tree which can be thought as

```
               2
        1                3
A            B        C         4
                             D       E
```

Therefore output needed is 00 for A, 01 for B, 10 for C, 110 for D, 111 for E
From the above look of the tree .. you can see that A, B, C, D, E has been put up linearly left to right for each of the NULL pointers in leaves

This is what i get from my `getCodes()` function

```
1 left child is A having code as 00
1 right child is B having code as 01
3 left child is C having code as 10
4 left child is D having code as 10
4 right child is E having code as 11
```

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: have a look at the edit

Comment: pass to getCodes one more argument identifying direction. Or linked list of previous directions, or array and depth level, and put current direction on array[level] place

Answer (score 1):

```
void inorder(char string[20],int index,tree *root)//index is sent 0 from main
{
  if(root)
  {
    string[index]='0';
    string[index+1]='\0';
    inorder(string,index+1,root->left);//Add 0 at end when you go to left
    printf("%s\n",string);
    string[index]='1';
    string[index]='\0';
    inorder(string,index+1,root->right);//Add 1 at end when you go to right
  }
}
```